# XML sent by PHP Curl

Tags: php, xml, php-curl

I've written some code that is attempting to send data from mySQL database in xml form via phpCurl to another server. No error appears but how do I test if its correct? Can anyone spot any errors?

```
<?php

$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'edgeserver');
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}

$sql = "SELECT SessionLogs.sessionid, SessionLogs.eventid, BetStatus.BetStatus, EventStatus.EventStatus, SessionLogs.activestatusid
FROM SessionLogs INNER JOIN
EventStatus ON SessionLogs.eventstatusid = EventStatus.EventStatusID INNER JOIN
BetStatus ON SessionLogs.betstatusid = BetStatus.BetStatusID
where ActiveStatusID = 1
";




$res = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);


$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openmemory();
$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xmlstring = $xml->outputMemory();
$xml->startElement('Alive');
$xml->writeAttribute('timestamp', date('c'));

if($res === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $xml->startElement("Event");

  $xml->writeAttribute('sessionid', $row['sessionid']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('eventid', $row['eventid']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('BetStatus', $row['BetStatus']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('EventStatus', $row['EventStatus']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('activestatusid', $row['activestatusid']);

  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();
$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();


$url='HTTP://WWW.XXXXXXXXXX.INFO'; // URL


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

Thanks

Comment: did you got any error while running the script

Comment: @Ramki no I didn't get any errors. I'm not sure if its working, I'm looking for suggestions on how I can test it. Thanks.

Comment: you can test it by receiving the data on the receiving end...

Comment: Check the curl response object $ch for errors.

e.g. // Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}